# Error Deleting memberships

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I am running CiviCRM 5.20.1 with WordPress 5.3.2. We have decided to redefine a membership type (actually an annual recertification) and I needed to delete the current members before I upload a sanitized version of the data (error free and more complete data).

I originally posted this question believing the memberships had not be deleted. They were. It would still be nice to fix this appearance of a problem.

Anyway, I am getting the following error when I delete the current members:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1260 in
 **/home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php** on line **632**

 **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function delete() on
 null in /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:664

Stack trace: 
#0 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php(613): CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::deleteMembership('1260', false) 
#1 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Form/Task/Delete.php(83): CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::del('1260') 
#2 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(495): CRM_Member_Form_Task_Delete->postProcess() 
#3 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Done.php(75): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess() 
#4 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Done->perform(Object(CRM_Member_Form_Task_Delete), 'done') 
#5 /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Pa 

in **/home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php** on line **664** There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions. 



 Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

I've looked at the lines in question, but I don't see (or understand) the problem. Any suggestions to move this project forward?

Comment: Is there an associated error in your Civicrm ConfigAndLog Log? It sometimes will have more information. https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: @LyonsDigital This error message is incomplete.  I reformatted it to make it clear that step 5 is missing data, as is the line below.  Could you please check your log and fill in missing parts, especially extra steps?

Comment: Also, confirm that the membership with ID 1260 still exists?

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening in the deleteMembership function, and the error says: you're trying to execute the method "delete" on an empty (i.e. null) object. The object that is "null" is expected to be a membership object.

That suggests that the code might have been running two copies in parallel - e.g. perhaps you clicked twice on the delete button (would not be difficult, since you're trying to do a mass delete on a lot of memberships).

Comment: Not sure how to test this hypothesis, but it's entirely likely.

Comment: Try repeating your mass membership delete?